# jquery change event when image src changes

Tags: jquery, html

```
$('img.product_image').attr('src').change(function() {
    alert($('img.product_image').attr('src'));
});
```

Hi ya'll

I am trying to write some code that will alert the img.product_image when the src changes, but when I run my page and click a button to change the image src, the alert does not come up...is my syntax wrong?

here is the image:

```
<img class="product_image colorbox-1160" id="product_image_1160" alt="Black Onyx Ring" title="Black Onyx Ring" src="https://www.taranmarlowjewelry.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/Black-Onyx-Ring.jpg" width="400">
```

and the image src would change when I would click on one of these thumbnails:

```
<div class="wpcart_gallery" style="text-align:center; padding-top:5px;">
    <a rev="https://www.taranmarlowjewelry.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/DSC_0162.jpg" class="thickbox cboxElement" rel="Black Onyx Ring" href="https://www.taranmarlowjewelry.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/DSC_0162.jpg" title="DSC_0162">
        <img width="50" height="50" src="https://www.taranmarlowjewelry.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/DSC_0162-50x50.jpg" class="attachment-gold-thumbnails colorbox-1160 " alt="DSC_0162" title="DSC_0162">
    </a>
    <a rev="https://www.taranmarlowjewelry.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/Black-Onyx-Ring1.jpg" class="thickbox cboxElement" rel="Black Onyx Ring" href="https://www.taranmarlowjewelry.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/Black-Onyx-Ring1.jpg" title="Black Onyx Ring">
        <img width="50" height="50" src="https://www.taranmarlowjewelry.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/Black-Onyx-Ring1-50x50.jpg" class="attachment-gold-thumbnails colorbox-1160 " alt="Black Onyx Ring" title="Black Onyx Ring">
    </a>
    <a rev="https://www.taranmarlowjewelry.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/Black-Onyx-Ring.jpg" class="thickbox" rel="Black Onyx Ring" href="https://www.taranmarlowjewelry.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/Black-Onyx-Ring.jpg" title="Black Onyx Ring">
        <img width="50" height="50" src="https://www.taranmarlowjewelry.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/Black-Onyx-Ring-50x50.jpg" class="attachment-gold-thumbnails colorbox-1160 " alt="Black Onyx Ring" title="Black Onyx Ring">
    </a>
</div>
```

Comment: you have to trigger an event using `trigger()` when you're changing its `src`.

Comment: `$('img.product_image').attr('src')` equates to a string, so the subsequent `.change()` is an error.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You can use `.load` event in this case:

```
$('img.product_image').on('load', function () {
 alert($('img.product_image').attr('src'));
});
```

Comment: load is not like change src event. ( timeline differences)

Comment: @RoyiNamir:But that will be getting fire every time image loads.

Comment: Im just saying that he might want to do something when src change without waiting for the img do download

Comment: using setinterval to check src is the only option that OP will have in that case.

Comment: This will triggered when image is first loaded which is not actually the `src` attribute changed.

Answer (score 8):

This code should work more reliably than answers that use 'load':

```
// ensures this works for some older browsers
MutationObserver = window.MutationObserver || window.WebKitMutationObserver || window.MozMutationObserver;

// the element you want to observe. change the selector to fit your use case
var img = document.querySelector('img.product_image')

new MutationObserver(function onSrcChange(){
  // src attribute just changed!!! put code here
  alert($('img.product_image').attr('src'))
})
  .observe(img,{attributes:true,attributeFilter:["src"]})
```

While some answers that use the 'load' event may work most of the time, the load event fires after the 'src' finishes downloading. That event may be delayed if the download takes a while or it may never fire if there is an issue downloading (which happens if the image times out or when you set src to an image that doesn't exist or is invalid, like an empty string ).

BTW jQuery isnt required but if you really want to use it you can get the target img element like so:

```
var img = $('img.product_image').get(0)
```

Comment: Much better answer! This solution works on each time when src is refreshed, instead of once when load first time.

Answer (score 4):

You could make use of load event if you like

```
$("img.product_image").load(function(){
     alert("New image loaded");
});
```

Jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/5WFjj/)

Answer (score -1):

If I understood your question right, try this:

Let's say your HTML is something like this:

```
<img class="product_image" src="first.png">
```

You can get the attr() with jQuery like this:

```
$(".product_image").attr("src","second.png");
```

and then using your buttons you load a click function like:

```
$('yourButtons').click(function() {
    $('.product_image').attr('src','second.jpg');
});
```

Comment: I think he wants to catch the event when the img src has been changed dynamically. 

An example: using dropbox and you are uploading an image inside and would like to do something more ( fire ajax call ).