# Get IMG SRC and put it on Input Value

Tags: javascript

Javascript (not jquery) to get an images src, and put it on a hidden input value via onclick.

```
var imgsrc = document.getElementById("imgsrc").src;

function changeValue(){document.getElementById("type").value="imgsrc here";
```

so here's the hidden input

```
<input id="type" name="type" type="hidden" value="">
```

and the whole process to happen via the onclick

```
.. onclick="changeValue()">
```

So how can i make it automatically put the imgsrc on the value like i thought it would be .value="imgsrc here";

Comment: Do you have a question? Please edit and include some question so we know what you’re having trouble with

Comment: how can i make it automatically put the imgsrc on the value like i thought it would be .value="imgsrc here";

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean something like :

```
function changeValue() {
    document.getElementById("type").value = document.getElementById("imgsrc").src;
}
```

Comment: Yes this was exactly what i was trying to do. Appreciated.

Comment: one more question if i am allowed please, can i make this realtime updated, without the need of onclick, everytime the imgsrc src is updated, to update the typevalue also using javascript?

Comment: Who is updating the src of the image ? If you have access to such function then edit it to include a call to `changeValue()`.

Comment: That's the issue, i do not have such access, it is a real-time change game which i need updates of thats why..

Comment: I see, please take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21163954/jquery-change-event-when-image-src-changes). Try the proposed solution there, if it does not work for you, I can suggest something using `setInterval`.

Answer (score 2):

This question is quite vague. Is this what you are looking for?

```
function changeValue(){document.getElementById("type").value = imgsrc;}
```

Comment: a question if i am allowed please, can i make this realtime updated, without the need of onclick, everytime the imgsrc src is updated, to update the typevalue also using javascript?

Comment: Without more code I'm a little unsure what you're asking. But I think you might be looking for this:

You can use "onchange(changeValue)" instead of "onclick(changeValue)" to achieve this.

Comment: If you post your code please, and a little bit more of an explanation as to what you're trying to do, I don't mind taking a look at it and helping as much as I can.