# javascript image src change event (not load event)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image

I'm trying to implement the following: User clicks a small thumbnail (low resolution image), and big image is set at the same source. Asynchronously, higher resolution image is being downloaded, and rendered to big image when the download is ready. While downloading, there should be indicator next to the low-res image that higher resolution picture is being downloaded. Also, images should always be retrieved from browser cache when they are once downloaded.

I have tried the following approach (not complete solution but more like experimenting)

```js
$('#bigphoto').on('load', function() {
  console.log('loaded');
  if ($('#bigphoto').attr('src').includes('type=low-res')) {
    $('#loading').show();
  } else {
    $('#loading').hide();
  }
});

function paivitaKuva(kuvaEl) {

  var src = kuvaEl.getAttribute('src');
  var r_src = kuvaEl.getAttribute('r-src');

  $('#bigphoto').attr('src', src);
  $('#bigphoto').attr('src', r_src);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img id="bigphoto" src="http://www.viikonloppu.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/lotoflaughters.com_-619x428.jpg?c3bc1b" />

<img id="thumbnail" src="https://i.pinimg.com/736x/01/c0/1c/01c01c45cb997f16675c5a5825645ceb--funny-happy-birthdays-pictures-of.jpg" r-src="https://www.manitowoccranes.com/~/media/Images/news/2014/Potain-China-hi-res.jpg" onClick="paivitaKuva(this)" )
/>

<div id="loading">loading</div>
```

There are couple of problems:

- load event triggers *after* download is ready, not when the src is being changed
- if the image is being retrieved from browser cache, seems like load event won't always trigger consistently
- There are actually list of different thumbnails and just a single big photo. I'm considered what happens if the user rapidly changes the photos

How to cleanly implement this using javascript?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jquery change event when image src changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21163954/jquery-change-event-when-image-src-changes)

Answer (score 1):

```
﻿<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>Thumbnail View Sample</title>

    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">

        // Global variables
        var loadingFlag = false;
        var statusElem = null;
        var hrElem = null;
        var hrIMG = null;

        function processSelection(tnElem) 
        {
            var hrSrc = null;

            try 
            {

                if (!loadingFlag) 
                {
                    loadingFlag = true;

                    statusElem.innerHTML = "Loading...";

                    hrElem.src = tnElem.src;
            hrElem.setAttribute("width", "64");
            hrElem.setAttribute("height", "64");

                    hrSrc = tnElem.getAttribute("hrsrc");

                    loadHRImage(hrSrc);
                }
                else 
                {
                    alert("Currently loading another image.\r\nOnly one image can be loaded at a time.\r\nTry again, later.");
                }
            }
            catch (e) 
            {
                alert("processSelection Error:  " + e.Message);
            }
            finally 
            {

            }
        }


        function loadHRImage(url) 
        {
            try 
            {
                hrIMG.src = url;
            }
            catch (e) 
            {
                alert("loadHRImage Error:  " + e.Message);
            }
            finally 
            {

            }
        }


        function setHRImage() 
        {
            var error = false;

            try 
            {
                hrElem.src = hrIMG.src;

                error = (hrIMG.width==0 || hrIMG.height==0);

        if(!error)
        {
            hrElem.setAttribute("width", hrIMG.width.toString());
            hrElem.setAttribute("height", hrIMG.height.toString());
        }
            }
            catch (e) 
            {
                error = true;
                alert("setHRImage Error:  " + e.Message);
            }
            finally 
            {
                loadingFlag = false;
                if (error) statusElem.innerHTML = "Loading...failed.";
                else statusElem.innerHTML = "Loading...completed.";
            }
        }


    </script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="theStatus" ><b>Select a Thumbnail Image to View the High Resolution version</b></div><hr/>
<table>
<tr>
<td style="vertical-align: top">
<table>
<tr><td><img id="tn0" alt="" src="https://i.pinimg.com/736x/01/c0/1c/01c01c45cb997f16675c5a5825645ceb--funny-happy-birthdays-pictures-of.jpg" width="64" height="64" hrsrc="https://www.manitowoccranes.com/~/media/Images/news/2014/Potain-China-hi-res.jpg" onclick="processSelection(this)" title="Click to view High Resolution version" /></td></tr>
<tr><td><img id="tn1" alt="" src="https://i.pinimg.com/736x/01/c0/1c/01c01c45cb997f16675c5a5825645ceb--funny-happy-birthdays-pictures-of.jpg" width="64" height="64" hrsrc="https://www.manitowoccranes.com/~/media/Images/news/2014/Potain-China-hi-res.jpg" onclick="processSelection(this)" title="Click to view High Resolution version" /></td></tr>
<tr><td><img id="tn2" alt="" src="https://i.pinimg.com/736x/01/c0/1c/01c01c45cb997f16675c5a5825645ceb--funny-happy-birthdays-pictures-of.jpg" width="64" height="64" hrsrc="https://www.manitowoccranes.com/~/media/Images/news/2014/Potain-China-hi-res.jpg" onclick="processSelection(this)" title="Click to view High Resolution version" /></td></tr>
</table>
</td>
<td></td>
<td>
<img id="hrImage" alt="" src="" />
</td>
</tr>
</table>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    // Initialize global variables
    statusElem = document.getElementById("theStatus");
    hrElem = document.getElementById("hrImage");
    hrIMG = new Image();
    hrIMG.addEventListener('loadend', setHRImage, false);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is a variation and strictly a sample WITHOUT using jQuery.  Give it a try and see if it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

```
load event triggers after download is ready, not when the src is being changed

- have you considered using an onclick event to trigger the toggling of the "status" div content?

if the image is being retrieved from browser cache, seems like load event won't always trigger consistently

- see previous suggestion (onclick event for each thumbnail img element)... also, you are using some kind of querystring in the initial Hi-Res IMG src, perhaps you should do the same when loading subsequent Hi-Res sources (e.g. - time stamp value at time of click event)

There are actually list of different thumbnails and just a single big photo. I'm considered what happens if the user rapidly changes the photos

- you could create a global variable, e.g. - var loadingFlag = false, that you toggle between true and false while processing the requests...if one is currently being processed, ignore subsequent clicks on the IMG elements...after the Hi-Res IMG is loaded, set the variable back to 'false'
```

Comment: onclick event isn't sufficient, as image changes two times per single click. The status is coupled with low-res image being shown, until high-res is available