# JQuery changing image

Tags: jquery, onchange

Hi I have this problem: when a value is selected in a select field the "src" attribute of an image is changed. I need to get the src value of that image AFTER is changed by jquery.

I do this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ) {

    $('.woocommerce-main-image img').on('change', function() {
        var a = $('.woocommerce-main-image img').attr('src');
    });
});
```

But in this way I get the src BEFORE the change. 
How can I get the src value after changing?

Comment: `change` is not a valid event of an `<img>` element. What you want is actually to fire a custom event on the element element when you are modifying the src attribute in another part of your code, and then you can simply listen to this custom event. Can you show us the code where the `src` attribute is manipulated?

Comment: Since you're changing the `src` value when you change the selection in the `select` field and assuming that this is done in JavaScript, why don't you simply add your code there? You already have the new value of `src`.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `change` you should be listening to `load` event.

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XUL/image):

> This event handler will be called on the image element when the image has finished loading. This applies whether the image is applied via the src attribute or the list-style-image style property. If you change the image, the event will fire again when the new image loads. This event will not bubble up the element tree.

```js
$("#img1").on("load", function(){
  console.log($(this).attr('src'));
});

setTimeout(function() {
  $("#img1").attr("src", "//placehold.it/200");
},5000);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img src="//placehold.it/150" id="img1" />
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use load event

```
$('.woocommerce-main-image img').on('load', function () {
    alert($(this).attr('src'));
});
```

check [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21163954/jquery-change-event-when-image-src-changes) for more information

Answer (score 0):

You should try to use the current object instead of the global selector, like this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ) {

  $('.woocommerce-main-image img').on('change', function() {

    var a = $(this).attr('src');

  });
```

});