# Preview for Image before Upload

Tags: html, laravel, preview

I am not sure why my Code does not work.

Here is my Javascript:

```
function readURL(input) {

        if (input.files && input.files[0]) {

            var reader = new FileReader();

            reader.onload = function (e) {

                $('#previewHolder').attr('src', e.target.result);

            }

            reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);

        }

    }

    $("#images").change(function(){

        readURL(this);

    });
```

And here is my Html:

```
<form id="form1">
                    <input value="" type="file" id="images" name="images[]" accept="image/*" multiple/>
                    <img src="#" id="previewHolder" width="200px" alt="x.png"/>
                </form>
```

I have found several stackoverflow with literally the same Code and it works there. I can't find the missing Piece.

Comment: how come it doesn't work? do you have any errors in the console? w

Comment: @matiit no i dont. it should show thats why i am so confused. maybe its because of the library?    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.js"></script>
other then that i cannot understand why it doesnt work

Comment: So I see the reader.onload declaration, but I'm not sure where the file is actually being set.  What are you passing in as the URL?  Can you maybe post an example of the crafted URL?

Comment: can you try jquery on method and console the output ?

Comment: @MichaelMiller im sorry i didnt quiet get what u asked. i am in a practica so i dont have a lot of experience in the field yet. as far as i understood the reader.onload activates the moment the file is being loaded on the page. in the function i call the html id. with the attr. i get the src which would be in this case img src="#".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Law, if you reference [this](https://api.jquery.com/change/) doc, you'll notice that the change event only fires on `<input>` and `<textarea>` tags...  You need to use `$("#images").load(`, as outlined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21163954/jquery-change-event-when-image-src-changes).

Comment: but i am accessing an input tag with the .change(). so it should work the moment someone inputs a file. i just found the problem. i had jquery ui and jquery below it loaded. basically had it twice in there and after i removed the second one it worked fine.

Comment: Nice!  They must include code to fire on loud within the change method for images...  They need to update their doc...  ;)

Answer (score 0):

Basically the code here is correct. it didnt work because i had jquery twice loaded. once i removed the tag on layout it worked just fine. but note this code is just for single image preview files.